# Call to a member function fill() on array while trying to add value to session variable

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create a multi step form on laravel. But when I try storing the values to the session i get the error 
"**Call to a member function fill() on array** "

```
public function postStepOne(Request $request) {
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'desc' => 'required',
        'followers' => 'required'
    ]);
    if(empty($request->session()->get('info'))){
        $info= new info();
        $info->fill($validatedData);
        $request->session()->put('info', $info);
    }else {
        $info= $request->session()->get('info');
        $info->fill($request->all());
        $request->session()->put('info', $info);
    }
    return redirect('/step-two');
}
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You're trying to call the `fill` method on an array instead of an object. I assume it's concerning the `fill` call inside `else`. Have you dumped `$request->session()->get('info')` to see what you get?

Comment: When I dump '$request->session()->get('info');' i get an array. What I intend to do is keep filling the '$info' variable with data passed on through the form as the user keep proceeding through the steps and so that in the end when the user submits the form, all the data collected in the session can be inserted into the database

Comment: *"When I dump '$request->session()->get('info');' i get an array."* -- so not an instance of your `info` class, but a native array that doesn't have a `->fill()` member function. Is there any other code that also tries to set the `info` value into your session and uses an array instead of an `info` object?

Comment: You both are right, the '$info' in the 'else' is causing the trouble and that is because it is defined by an array instead of an object. Thank you folks